# Separate vector of strings with quotations and comma in R

Tags: r, string, paste

I have a vector of words that I would like to make one string separated by quotations and commas.

Here is my vector

```
vec = c("AAPL", "MSFT")
```

I am trying to make the output look like this"

```
print(string)
"AAPL","MSFT"
```

Here is my current attempt

```
string = paste0(vec, collapse = ",")

print(string)
"AAPL,MSFT"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `dQuote`

```
out <- paste(dQuote(vec, FALSE), collapse=",")
cat(out, "\n")
#"AAPL","MSFT"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `shQuote` + `cat`:

```
cat(shQuote(vec, FALSE), sep=",")
"AAPL","MSFT"
```